# Use AngularJS to save the text of a element in Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

User on my website can use a input field to search for a movie title. Example, they type in "Star" and my Angular searchController outputs a JSON request from the internet movie database and displays all the titles with the name "Star" in it in a drop down display.

Now I want users to add the title of the movie (and poster etc, but that's later) to their movielist. I've completed the https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ tutorial which gave me some clues to store data but I find it very hard to completely understand how to do this.

I´ve created this little bit of jquery code that stores the title of the movie into a variable,

```
  $("#showresults").on("click", ".search_results", function() {
    var movieTitle = $(this).find(".ng-binding").text();
    console.log (movieTitle)
  });
```

So I want to store the value of the variable `movieTitle` into my database, or ofcourse straight from the value of the element instead of storing it in a variable first. I've generated a model that created a movie table with some columns I need,

scherma.rb

```
create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "image"
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "release_date"
end
```

Here's the searchControllers code.

.controller('searchCtrl', [

```
  '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.search = function() {

      var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
      var service = '/search/movie';
      var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
      var search = $scope.searchquery
      var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
      var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

      $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          if (status == 200) {
            $scope.movieList = data.results;
            console.log($scope.movieList)
          } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          }

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        });
    }

    $("#search_input").keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val()) {
        //
      } else {
          $(".search_results").remove();
      }
    });

    $("#showresults").on("click", ".search_results", function() {
      var movieTitle = $(this).find(".ng-binding").text();
      console.log (movieTitle)
    });

  }
```

Comment: I didn't understand if you need help to build the rails part or the angular one.

Comment: It's a litle bit of both. I have some basic knowledge of Rails, generating models etc and how to use controllers but I don't know how to start the Angular part. How do I save the text stored in the variable into the database.

Comment: do you mind sharing your angular code? I don't think you need JQuery to retrieve values if you use angular objects to store the values for you.

Comment: I don't have a lot of code yet, just my searchController.